# Issue dynamically generating a form using angularJS

Tags: angularjs, input, dynamically-generated, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to dynamically generate a form using angularJS.
Normally this works well however this form has dynamic types, some should be text, an email, and the important one is password.
Really I would like it to work for everything but password is the most important.

Currently my code is

```
<input ng-repeat="input in credForm.loginForm.fields" type="{{input.fieldType}}"
ng-model="credForm.loginForm.fields[$index].value" ng-model-options="{ updateOn:
'blur' }" placeholder="{{input.fieldName}}..." ng-required="!input.optional">
```

Everything about this is great, however type doesn't work i get the error "Error: type property can't be changed" which is apparently a security issue. How do we fix this the angular way without having to do something aweful by generating a element in javascript add adding it as a child with an ID.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it's handled in a directive I'm using -- note the compile at the bottom of the link function. In your case you'd probably want a directive just for the type - so you can continue to use your existing code -- something like `field-type="{{input.fieldType}}"` and then just use the `element.find("input").attr("type", attrs.fieldType)` followed by the compile.

```
  angular.module("schemaForm").directive("schemaFormField", 
    ['$compile', '$templateCache', '$dialog', '$q', 
    function ($compile, $templateCache, $dialog, $q) {
        return {
            restrict: "EA",
            replace: true,
            require: "^form",
            scope: { 
                schema: "=",
                model: "=",
                field: "=",
                required: "=",
                onClick: "@",
                editAs: "@"
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, formController) {
                var template;
                var searchBox = $templateCache.get("searchBox.html");

                scope.formState = formController; // form state checking (pristine, etc.)

                scope.opts = {
                    backdrop: true,
                    keyboard: true,
                    backdropClick: true,
                    template: searchBox, 
                    //templateUrl: 'schemaFormSearchBox.html',
                    controller: 'schemaFormSearchCtrl'
                };

                // enables ng-show of label                
                scope.isEmpty = function() { 
                  return typeof scope.model[scope.field] === 'undefined';
                };

                // launches search dialog on ng-click
                scope.search = function() {
                  scope.opts.item = scope.schema;
                  var d = $dialog.dialog(scope.opts);
                  d.open().then(function (result) {
                    if (result) { // don't overwrite if cancelled
                      scope.model[scope.field] = result;
                    }
                  });
                };

                // perhaps throw exeception instead?
                if (scope.schema === undefined) {
                  return $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                }

                // assigned template according to form field type
                template = (scope.schema["enum"] !== undefined) && 
                           (scope.schema["enum"] !== null) ? 
                           $templateCache.get("enumField.html") : 
                           $templateCache.get("" + scope.schema.type + "Field.html");
                element.html(template);

                // update attributes - type, ng-required, ng-pattern, name
                if (scope.schema.type === "number" || scope.schema.type === "integer") {
                    element.find("input").attr("type", "number");
                }
                element.find("input").attr("ng-required", scope.required);
                if (scope.schema.pattern) {
                    element.find("input").attr("ng-pattern", "/" + scope.schema.pattern + "/");
                }
                element.find("input").attr("name", scope.field);

                // compile template against current scope
                return $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            }
        };
    }]);
})
```

Comment: If you need help crafting a directive that's limited to just setting the type, add a comment and I'll post some detailed code.

Comment: I guess that would be the angular way, Custom directive to generate input tags with dynamic types as a template. I need to go out but if I don't receive a better answer by the time I get back I'll mark answer.

Comment: So I took a dive into some code and actually found <input hh ng-repeat="field in fields" type="{{field.type}}"> ... So apparently it is possible.

However I can't for the life of me find what hh is... I have access to all of the code, and I have searching in all files for hh 1730 hits 90% have to do with date format and a few hits in encoded files, use in the template but no where do I see it defined as a directive or anything of the sort.

Comment: I don't know what the hh is, but having the ng-repeat input statement assign type dynamically makes sence - since it will be compiled by the ngRepeat directive.  Of course you can't easily wrap your fields with things like labels and spans and help blocks if you go that route.

Comment: I don't know what the hh is either but at the moment I am assuming that it was something and has since been partially removed.

It makes sense that it should work however it doesn't work for me, it seems that ng-repeat might add <input> to the dom then attempt to change the type from default ("text") to "password" instead of compiling <input type="password"> directly.

I am going to setup a fiddle to test thing out in a bit more detailed manor.